# Android change color stroke (border) programmatically

Tags: android

I try change color "stroke", through  "GradientDrawable" but not work.

also, I don't know how get id stroke, and change only stroke (I see google, all example are failed)

My XML item

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/selectable_kachel_shape" >
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="2"
            android:useLevel="false" >
            <stroke android:width="11dp" android:color="#ff00ffff"/>
            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    </layer-list>

GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable) circleProgress.getBackground();

gd = (GradientDrawable) circleProgress.getBackground();
gd.setColor(Color.RED);

android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable
```

Here Works, but ... not get my item

```
    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
    gd.setColor(Color.RED);
    gd.setCornerRadius(10);
    gd.setStroke(2, Color.WHITE);


    circleProgress.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
```

**UPDATE** here Works, BUT NOT CHANGE MY STROKE (I TRIED WITH ID BUT NOT WORK)
ONLY WORK WITH ID ITEM.

```
GradientDrawable shape = (GradientDrawable) (layers.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.selectable_kachel_shape));
        shape.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_dark));
        circleProgress.setBackgroundDrawable(shape);
```

Comment: Instead of trying to do that by code, why don't you just use an xml StateList Selector?

Comment: I solved the error is setColor you need setstroke :)

Answer (score 15):

Instead of this you may be use any layout and apply your xml as selector and for that layout you apply dynamic backgrounds via `GradientDrawable`.

For example, main.xml:

```xml
<RelativeLayout 
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/shapes"/>
```

Then your xml, shapes.xml:

```xml
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/selectable_kachel_shape">
    <shape android:innerRadius="0dp" android:shape="ring" android:thicknessRatio="2" android:useLevel="false">
      <stroke android:width="11dp" android:color="#ff00ffff" />
      <gradient android:centerColor="#FFFFFF" android:endColor="#FFFFFF" android:startColor="#FFFFFF" android:type="sweep" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

And write following code in your activity.

```java
RelativeLayout mainLayout= (RelativeLayout ) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
gd.setColor(Color.RED);
gd.setCornerRadius(10);
gd.setStroke(2, Color.WHITE);
mainLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
```

For more `GradientDrawable` use the link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html.

Comment: You never edit "stroke" default from XML, gd.setStroke(2???,red), you put new value for stroke and color, not from <stroke android:width="11dp" android:color="#ff00ffff"/>.

Comment: I solved, read my coment from my post, And thanks for your example :)